# MySQL return alternative record if no record returned

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following

```
-------------------------
|  aid  |  tid  |  dft  |
-------------------------
|   1   |   1   |   Y   |
-------------------------
|   1   |   2   |   N   |
-------------------------
|   2   |   3   |   Y   |
-------------------------
|   3   |   4   |   Y   |
-------------------------
|   3   |   5   |   N   |
-------------------------
```

I want to query the table to get the *tid* out based on *aid* and *tid* but if the *tid* does not exist for that *aid* then it should return the default *tid* (identified by Y in the *dft* column).

I have tried the following which does not throw an error but returns NULL

```
SELECT

IF (
    t1.tid IS NOT NULL,
    t1.tid,
    (
        SELECT
            t2.tid
        FROM
            table t2
        WHERE
            t2.aid = 1
        AND t2.dft = 'Y'
    )
) AS tid
FROM
    table t1
WHERE
    t1.aid = 1
AND t1.tid = 3
```

As that code is looking up *tid* 3 with *aid* 1 that doesn't exist so should return *tid* of 1 as that is what is marked as Y in the *dft* column.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tid
 FROM table t1
WHERE t1.aid = 1
  AND t1.tid = 3
UNION   
SELECT tid
 FROM table t1
WHERE t1.aid = 1
  AND t1.tid <> 3
  AND dft = 'Y'
```

If the combination of `aid` and `tid` is unique then you can use this version:

```
SELECT tid
 FROM table t1
WHERE t1.aid = 1
  AND (t1.tid = 3 OR dft = 'Y')
ORDER BY dft LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks. The latter did the trick - obvious really, but you know what it's like when you stare at something too long!! A second set of eyes is always good.

Answer (score 0):

This would work in MSSQL, but I dont have access to a MySQL server to try it

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.aid=1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.tid=3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, CASE WHEN t1.dft='Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```